# Remove popover of master view in splitViewController

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I want to remove the master view popover of a `splitViewController` when `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called. Since the popover removal is done automatically I couldn't get to the `popoverController` in order to use `dismissPopoverAnimated:YES`

Any idea how to dismiss it?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and found the answer here:
[UISplitViewController in portrait: how to hide master popover programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721583/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-how-to-hide-master-popover-programatically)

It was answered on the morning of the day you asked...