# dismiss mastersplitview from uibarbutton in mastesplitview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've implemented a UISpliview and it works great. But I would like to add an option for the users to dismiss the masterview by pressing a button in the masterview (so it would be doing the same action, which is trickered by touching the detailview). Is this possible to do? I've update with the code, which I believe should work, but it doesn't do anything?

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
barButtonItem = _backButton;
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:  (UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
// Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
self.masterPopoverController = nil; 
}

//the action, which gets called once the button is pressed. 
- (IBAction)backToFullDetailView:(id)sender
{
    [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

[image: Masterview shown with button (help)]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to dismiss your popover. A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422812/how-can-i-dismiss-the-master-view-from-a-uisplitviewcontroller-in-ios-5-1). You are looking at something like `[youPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated: YES];`

Comment: How is a popover connected to a `UISplitViewController`?

Comment: it is a property of the detail view controller: self.masterPopoverController

Comment: I have never seen such property within the UIKit references. Could you please quote the relevant part from the documentation?

Comment: I got it by creating a SplitViewController template - i don't recall to have seen it in the official doc